# Selective Apache v2.2 Authentication

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap, subnet

I would like to modify this snippet so that connections from a certain IP subnet will be accepted without a requirement for authentication.

Is this possible?

TIA

Shaun

```
<Location "/rssbus">
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthType Basic
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://blah.com:3628/DC=blah,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)" STARTTLS
    AuthLDAPBindDN "bdn@eu.blah.com"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword XXXXXXXX
    AuthLDAPRemoteUserIsDN off
    Require valid-user
    Require ldap-group mygroup,OU=IT,OU=Groups,OU=gong,DC=blah,DC=com

    ProxyPass https://stgjo/bus
    ProxyPassReverse https://stgjo/bus
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to add a Satisfy directive. Like it's described [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#satisfy)

So that would give you :

```
<Location "/rssbus">
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthType Basic
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://blah.com:3628/DC=blah,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)" STARTTLS
    AuthLDAPBindDN "bdn@eu.blah.com"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword XXXXXXXX
    AuthLDAPRemoteUserIsDN off
    Require valid-user
    Require ldap-group mygroup,OU=IT,OU=Groups,OU=gong,DC=blah,DC=com
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from your.ip.address.allowed
    Satisfy Any 

    ProxyPass https://stgjo/bus
    ProxyPassReverse https://stgjo/bus
```